# How to use python async def without awaiting on every parent function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I was wondering if it possible to create async function without setting main as async.

I have a function call like this:

```
async def C:
    t = asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(command)
    ...
    await t

def B:
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    C()
    <How to await for C?>

def A:
    B()
```

I'm unable to await for C (either as a task or a future). The function exits immediately after starting C(). I've tried loop.create_task and loop.run_until_complete(task) but nothing seems to work.

I don't want to set all parent function calls as async up to main(). Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
My original problem is to run multiple shell commands in parallel (which start another application) from a python function and then wait for their results.

Comment: If you want to wait for C being C your only async function, why bothering to use async anyway? You can use a blocking mechanism.

Comment: @Netwave Could you please elaborate on what blocking mechanisms exist in Python? I'm very new to it. I found that to await on asyncio.create_subprocess_shell, I had to create C as async as well.

Comment: You can use `loop.run_until_complete(C())`, but that won't work if that whole code is already inside an event loop. Asyncio event loops don't nest.

Comment: @user4815162342 Then what is the correct approach to launch multiple asyncio.subprocesses and wait for them. Could you please suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Also, I had to create event loop as it was reportedly not found for the current thread.

Comment: @user4815162342 If I understand you correctly, you're saying C() and asyncio.create_subprocess_shell() run in different event loops? How to verify this then.

Comment: I'm not saying that at all, and at this point I don't understand what the question is. I tried to answer the actual question, which seemed to be "how do I block until an async function is executed?" You do that by calling `run_until_complete`. If you need to launch multiple tasks and so on, you should look into an asyncio tutorial, e.g. see `asyncio.run()` and `asyncio.create_task()`.

Comment: @user4815162342 My original problem is to run multiple shell commands in parallel (which starts another application) from a python function and wait for their results. I envisioned the above solution for this.

Comment: Please at least mention the original problem in the question, otherwise we're dealing with an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way to use asyncio in modern Python (3.7 and later) is something like:

```py
async def main():
    ... your code here ...

async.run(main())
```

To do multiple things in parallel, you can use `asyncio.gather`. For example:

```py
async def main():
    proc1 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(command1)
    proc2 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(command2)

    # wait in parallel for both processes to finish and obtain their statuses
    status1, status2 = await asyncio.gather(proc1.wait(), proc2.wait())
```